# Image problems when using jQuery Slideshowlite with DNN based website

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow, dotnetnuke, image-preloader

Basically, when the page opens, the images contained within the slideshow are temporarily stacked before being placed correctly into the slideshow.

I think this might be because DNN renders the images located in the HTML first before it runs through the script files. This results in a list of images (they're in < li > tags) placed one over the other (for about 2 seconds), before behaving normally.

Things Iv tried:

1. placing the script which calls the slideshow at the end of the HTML (Someone suggested this, no idea why it would work though).
2. hiding the div containing the images initially and then use a script that reveals the div using jquery and css once the document has loaded. (eg: display: none >>> display: block)

for those interested here's a link to the site (uses Bitly):
http ://bit.ly/gNfWRx

Much appreciated

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strategy #2 should work.  If you put a div around your current div / li items and you make that display:none or change the visibility.  Then in your jQuery document.ready after the slideshow initialization in run you would execute some jQuery to find that div and then show() it. Might take a little work but that strategy should work just fine.

Comment: Sorry about the late response but thanks dude, that worked just fine.